# nginx in docker doesn't work

Tags: docker, nginx

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx nodejs

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ADD Front-Dev/v2/desktop /usr/share/nginx/html/
ADD Front-Dev/v2/desktop /var/www/html/

# Append "daemon off;" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 90

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

and my `nginx.conf` has the following view:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       9000;
        server_name  localhost;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        index login.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }
}
```

In path `Front-Dev/v2/desktop` there is `login.html` file.

Docker image is built successfully by the following command: `sudo docker build --rm -t pitstop-nginx .`

Docker container was executed by `sudo docker run -p  9000:90 pitstop-nginx` and I  see it in `sudo docker ps`

However, when I go the link `http://localhost:9000/` or `http://localhost:9000/login.html` there is nothing. What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you forget `-p` flag: `docker run -p 9000:90 pitstop-nginx`?

Comment: @dvnguyen sorry, it's the typo in my question.

Comment: Can you run `docker logs <container_name>` to see what happened?

Comment: @dvnguyen there is only `Starting nginx nginx`. That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you nginx conf file is using port 9000 and you are exposing port 90.

it wouldn't work.

if your nginx is using port 9000, you should expose it. Then map it.

sudo docker run -p  9000:9000 pitstop-nginx

-p localhost_port:container_port